# How do you get the latest version of an s3 object using aws cli?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

Using the AWS CLI, how do I output a most recent VersionId string of an S3 object?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Simplifying @rynop's command:

```
aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket us-east-1--aws-blueprint.mydomain.com --prefix my/object/key.ext --query 'Versions[?IsLatest].[VersionId]' --output text
```

Comment: Was not aware of `--query` thanks.  Got rid of a dependency for me!

Comment: What are the S3 permissions are required for `list-object-versions` ? I'm getting `An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjectVersions operation: Access Denied`

Comment: @bits Please create a new Question rather than asking a question via a comment on an old Answer.

Comment: Added as a separate answer, but I believe you can go even simpler now and just use `head-object`: `aws s3api head-object --bucket us-east-1--aws-blueprint.mydomain.com --prefix my/object/key.ext --query 'VersionId' --output text`

Comment: Since `--query` is for client-side filtering, [pagination](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-usage-pagination.html) limits apply (i.e., maximum 1000 results). The order of [results](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjectVersions.html#API_ListObjectVersions_ResponseSyntax) is undefined, so the above request may return `null` in case an object has more than 1000 versions.

Answer (score 5):

```
aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket aws-blueprint.mybucket.com --prefix nested-stacks/apig/single-lambda-proxy-with-CORS.yaml | jq -r '.Versions[] | select(.IsLatest == true) | .VersionId'
```

Output looks like:
`o65j.nFiJ00D25lNPyzsbJ7rWktOoKmS`

Comment: One potentially useful caveat to keep in mind is that if the latest version of an object was created *very recently*, the latest version you find here may actually be a previous version.  ListObjects is eventually consistent, and it stands to reason that ListObjectVersions would be as well.  If it is absolutely critical to know the latest version, you will want to store the version-id elsewhere (e.g. in a database) when creating objects.

Comment: Yup understood thanks. For my particular use case, timing is not an issue

Answer (score 3):

There is another option to get the latest S3 object versionId.

To get it you have to simply set tag to that object with `aws s3api put-object-tagging` command. The output of that operation is only latest object versionId. By default it is returned as JSON, but with `--output text` option you will get it as only returned string.

Sample:

```
 $ VERSION_ID=$(aws s3api put-object-tagging --bucket bucket-name --key code.zip --tagging 'TagSet=[{Key=Lambda,Value=golang}]' --output text)
 $ echo $VERSION_ID
 6ubT3rNptpcZNGxEA6Cj2kAastuCyNL1
```

I believe it's best way to achieve it. The risk with `listObjectVersions` is that you might have more than pagination limit and then you will have to call it again from "NextToken" value. But with `put-object-tagging` it is reliable solution fir this usecase. Plus you get some more details stored on your object.

In my project I keep there details about the team responsible for the lambda, the code runtime for the ZIP and project repository name. So one someone spot that ZIP in the bucket it is easy to get such details.

Answer (score 1):

I believe an even simpler version of @JohnRotenstein's answer is:

```
aws s3api head-object --bucket us-east-1--aws-blueprint.mydomain.com --prefix my/object/key.ext --query 'VersionId' --output text
```

It's not documented, but a `HEAD` request on an object appears to return the metadata of the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

```
aws s3api list-object-versions --bucket <bucket-name> --prefix files/file1.txt
```

replace  with actual bucket name replace files/file1.txt with object name